# strange behavior with response from code behind css rounded corner dissapears in IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms, response

I was about to write a whole post on my situation "the rounded corner css style disappeared after post back" and post my code here ...

so instead of posting my code I have rebuilt both aspx via it's js scripts 
piece by piece and same with code behind...

then I discovered the issue !!

the line who was responsible, was `Response.Write("some value of a test");`

I could just stay with that and fix with eliminating the un necessary Line,  and actually delete this post just cause I have solved that issue , and that line was only a test,
just as you would use `Console.WriteLine()` in a console application..

and also I could always avoid `Response.Write()` via setting an Html element's `Text` and plot values.

**but** The Question remains , and also for my understanding, **why** does the `Response.Write()` eliminated my Rounded corner css style , isn't it a bug ?

how on earth it is related, where is there a clue or a warning for that issue ??

**Update**

this is the css which was fine till this incedent

```
    .Rounded
    {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: What version of IE? `border-radius` (assuming this is what you've used) is not supported in IE8 and under as it's a CSS3 property. Perhaps there is a doctype on the page forcing it to render under a lower version of IE?

Comment: @DGibbs it's IE9 .. Also it did show css ok before posting page that sent response write (by The Way Chrome did not have a problem)

Comment: @DGibbs it's a class i am using now for every project as it was being tested by other developers here , just add this class to an element and it's cros browser rounded corner (updating post with css in a minute)

Comment: Maybe the response write broke the markup and forced IE to render under a different standards mode? After the response.write, open up IE dev tools (F12) and check the document mode, I'd wager that it's not rendering under IE9..

Comment: @DGibbs it's such a shame that i am not up to date, i thought only FF and Chrome has this  i did not know that(: , sure i will check on that issue with the "new ie Dev Tools " (:

Comment: @DGibbs it just removed the class, left only one class i will try put style in to one class see what happens

Comment: @DGibbs tried it too, seems that no meter how you set it (separated classes or not ) it eliminates the rounded corner style)

Comment: Check the *`Document Mode` in IE.*

Comment: Is that after the `Response.Write("")`? Because this would probably break the markup and cause it to **not** render in standards mode.

Comment: @DGibbs sorry checked again it was Quirks, so the conclusion is you were right though i don't know what the resolution for this is  somehow forcing a supposed to be default mode to be the mode it is responding , nice catch !!

Comment: @DGibbs i am going to find out which college you applied to(: ... how do you know such a deep information on the markup .. broken browser renders after a post back

Comment: The resolution is to create well formed markup. If you just need this for testing then it shouldn't really matter, however, you could just create a `<asp:Label ...` within a `<p></p>` block and then set your test text equal to the labels text, it will output a `<span>` which is fine from a standards point of view

Comment: @DGibbs u should sumerise the highlights in 2 sentences i will come back to upvote your answer

Comment: Happy to help, I've added an answer should this be helpful to anyone else in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments..

The issue here is that your call to `Response.Write("some value of a test");` is breaking the markup on the page and causing IE to render in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) which is why your rounded borders are disappearing.

The solution would be to create well formed markup. You can check your HTML against your doctype using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it will inform you of any errors with your code.

A suggestion would be to create a standard `<asp:Label>` and assign your text to it rather than outputting a string with no tags.

You could even do: `Response.Write("<span>some value of test</span>");`

Comment: thanks for the valuable information Mr Gibbs (: nice to know all you have informed within this post!

Comment: ok one last question for this subject , accorrding to the solution part of your answer (W3C) ..., should i set the `docType` property so the page will render without the Quirk mode or thats not going to make any difference ?

Comment: i have used (default) transitional.dtd, meaning if i will change to stricts types like `xhtml1-strict.dtd` then it would react to the doctype and render as IE 9 standart ?

Comment: No, the text that your `Response.Write()` outputs is probably the cause of the document error since it would just be outputted as `some value of test` in the document and not wrapped in any tags.